# 'return' after a CLGeocoder has reverse geocoded data

Tags: objective-c, reverse-geocoding, clgeocoder

How do I only return a custom init method when it has finished reverse geocoding data?

Is there even a way to do this? I assumed I should just add 'return self' at the end of the completionHandler, but this just returns to the init method, as oppose to returning the init method.

All help is appreciated and thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can treat method selectors as data with

```
SEL    theSelector = @selector(initWithStuff:);
```

*theSelector* can now be passed around just like any other primitive data type.

Using ARC to call init method selectors with *performSelector:*, as in

```
id result = [target performSelector:theSelector];
```

is a bit tricky because the compiler does not know that the returned value needs to be released. If you can use a class method instead, you can then just live with the warning the compiler gives you or wrap that bit of code with

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
id result = [[Target class] performSelector:theSelector];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```